# Py-StackExchange filter by tag

Tags: python, tags, stackexchange-api

I'm using Py-StackExchange to get a list of recent questions from Stack Overflow. I know there is a way to get just a constant list of questions:

```
import stackexchange

so = stackexchange.Site(stackexchange.StackOverflow)

for question in so.questions(pagesize=10):
    print question
```

But this returns all questions across SO. I'm wondering if there is a parameter to filter the questions list by tag, i.e. `python`, `loops`, etc to only return questions in that tag. I've been cruising the web for almost an hour searching for results, even reading through some of the scripts, but I can't find anything.

Comment: Gotta keep this question in mind.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `tagged` keyword argument.

For example:

```
for question in so.questions(tagged=['python'], pagesize=10):
    print question
    assert 'python' in question.tags
```

Specifying `tagged=['python', 'loops']` will filter question that is tagged both `python` and `loops`.

Comment: Is there a documentation for pystack?

Comment: @falsetru: Ah, you poor thing! My apologies - nobody should ever find themselves in the situation of having to read my code. As far as documentation goes @samrap, you are probably best looking at the examples in the `demo/` subdirectory of the repo (https://github.com/lucjon/Py-StackExchange/tree/master/demo) or, for more peculiar problems, the FAQ (https://github.com/lucjon/Py-StackExchange/wiki/FAQ). The v1.1 API docs, still up on http://api.stackoverflow.com/1.1/usage, are also handy; there is usually a pretty close correlation between names in the HTTP API and Py-StackExchange.

Comment: @LucasJones is there a way to get questions by `newest`? I know you can get them by `active` with `recent_questions`, but I need them in order of newest

Comment: @samrap: I believe `so.questions(sort = 'creation')` should work.

Comment: How to retrieve the "Related tags" of a tag? I've added this as a separate [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20846479/how-to-retrieve-the-related-tags-of-a-tag-using-py-stackexchange).