# How to retrieve the "Related tags" of a tag using py-stackexchange?

Tags: python, stackexchange-api

Step 1: I would like to retrieve all the related tags of a particular tag using Py-stackexchange, much like what is accomplished [here](http://api.stackexchange.com/docs/related-tags#tags=pointers&filter=default&site=stackoverflow&run=true).

Step 2: I would like to find the intersection between two lists of related tags.

I am StackApp-agnostic, as long as it works!

**RELATED**:  [Py-StackExchange filter by tag](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19898666/307454)

Comment: The Related Tags API call is new in version 2.0 of the Stack Exchange API, see http://api.stackexchange.com/docs/change-log. Judging by [this issue in the Py-StackExchange project](https://github.com/lucjon/Py-StackExchange/issues/21), v2.0 support has not yet been implemented.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since [Py-StackExchange](https://stackapps.com/questions/198/py-stackexchange-an-api-wrapper-for-python?lq=1) does not support V2.0 yet, I struggled with [Stackpy](https://stackapps.com/questions/3417/stack-py-a-python-module-for-accessing-the-stack-exchange-2-1-api), but no luck there either (it could well be my incompetence too).

However, [SEAPI](https://stackapps.com/questions/3881/se-api-py-a-lightwight-python-wrapper-for-se-api?rq=1) is clean, efficient and was a breeze! And it uses the awesome [Requests:HTTP for Humans](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/) package to boot. It would be great if it incorporated authentication using [requests_oauthlib](https://github.com/requests/requests-oauthlib) as well.

Look [here](https://stackapps.com/a/4469/12360) for some sample code that the author of SEAPI has provided.